# Reporter.log() to print html link

Tags: java, html, selenium

I am working on selenium. I need to print an html link in the form of link/hyperlink.
For example:

```
System.out.println("https://www.google.co.in");
Reporter.log("https://www.google.co.in");
```

The above one prints the google link in text format but how can we print above one as in hyperlink/link format.

Is there any possible way to do this in selenium and also in java?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `System.out.println(...)` then you can only output raw text to the standard output. Now, if you want to be able to click on links in this standard output it is very important to know, how you're viewing this output. The standard way would be on the console or, with logging, maybe in a log file.

Links have to be supported by whatever displays those links if you want to be able to click them; some consoles do that automatically but many don't. And the same goes for text viewers. This has nothing to do with Java or Selenium.

What may make sense is if you're creating HTML files and viewing those with Selenium; in that case, you could of course create links, as any HTML browser will support them. But I doubt that's what you're currently attempting. (Correct me if I'm wrong.)

Comment: thank you for your response.i need to print the hyperlink in console but no need to click that link.just displaying that link in  console.if any possible for this let me know

Comment: If all you want to print is the url (= the address) then you can do that with `System.out.println(...)` or pretty much any logger. If you want to format it in any way, you'll have to take care of that yourself or give us more information; e.g. if you want to have the code for an HTML link you could do `System.out.println("<a href=" + url + " alt='alternative text'>Text to be displayed</a>");`